# Total by day in google sheets for a given month and year

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have the following table:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to write a formula that totals by each unique day in the month and year given in B1 and C1 thus the output should be:

[image]

I'm not sure how to start with this, googling seems to suggest the use of SUMIF.

[Sheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fD_bXPZ0YWgzb_pBP-kZV2_7pBkofCwm15kfHCT3Fx0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: answer and your sheet updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({A5:B, TIMEVALUE(C5:C)}, MONTH(A5:A)=MONTH(B1&1), YEAR(A5:A)=D1), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col3)'' 
  format sum(Col3)'[hh]:mm'", 0)
```

[image]